# How to send webkit user agents to one site version and all the rest to another?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am a humble graphic designer who is trying his best to learn development. I have a challenging question that I need some very clear and straightforward help with. From my research it seems that my solution can be accomplished with PHP or Javascript. I am totally an infant in both languages but I don't care which one is used. Preferably whatever is easiest for a noob like me.

So her is the deal…

I have a site I have just put together with a bunch of nice -webkit-transforms http://www.eameswords.com I want to send desktop Safari/Chrome to this site. I want to send iPad and iPhone to a separate touch enabled version too.

The kicker…

I have an Adobe flash version of the site as well. It does all the same interactivity. I want to send user agents for IE, Firefox and Opera to this version.

So I have 3 versions of my site!!

I would like to put all three versions of my site in three separate folders for organizational purposes.

So I need three types of user agent detection and three redirects:

iPad & iPhone (mobile Safari) ––––> folder01
Webkit Browsers (Safari/Chrome) ———> folder02
All other browsers (IE, Firefox, etc.) ————> folder03

This is crazy but I need some serious help to make this work. If anyone can give me a straightforward answer I would be happy to swap any of my design skills to pay-it-back. I say this because I need someone to literally write out the solution so I can process it, learn from it. I am really bad at piecing code together.

Thank you so much in advance!!!

Comment: You don't send useragents. Browsers send useragents to YOU, and your site can serve up different content based on those useragents.

Comment: My recommendation would be to have one site which degrades or performs differently based on the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)){
              window.location.replace("URL1");
        }
        else if ($.browser.webkit){
              window.location.replace("URL2");
        }
        else{
              window.location.replace("URL3");
        }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Evan! I got it to work just fine. It was funny because I copied your code into my page and it wasn't working and I was wondering what is wrong and then I realized I hadn't referenced the jquery framework——Im such a noob! But thanks SO much for the help. I have had such a good experience on this forum with people helping me out. I find that getting the answer helps me study why it worked and makes me learn faster than a book. Anyway, please keep helping people because it really makes a difference in their day!!!

Comment: Hey Evan, it seems like things have changed a little bit since you gave this answer because the redirect doesn't seem to work on recent browsers. Can you help me again? If you go to systemassasin.com/card you'll see the code I implemented, which worked for a long time but like I said is now broken…

Comment: try window.location = "VALUE" instead

Answer (score 1):

Check the user-agent header for the signature.

For example, in PHP:

```
$user_agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
//Condition checks: Does $user_agent equal the signature of a webkit browser?
//If not, redirect: header("Location: main.php?nonwebkit=true");
```

Search for the existence of "webkit" in the User agent string. If it exists, fine. Otherwise, redirect the user to the flash page.